# Javascript REGEX not end with some special character but return true

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
console.log(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+[~!@#$%^&*_+-=]+$/.test("123456"));
```

I think it should return `false` because the string does not end with a `~!@#$%^&*_+-=` character,
but it returns `true` when it runs.
Why does it return `true`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why the string "123456" match the regex "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+[~!@#$%^&*_+-=]+$/" ? it is not have one or more character in [~!@#$%^&*_+-=]

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Including a hyphen in a regex character bracket?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3697202)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `+-=` is a range. If you look at the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set), you can see that `+-=` includes `+`, `-`, `.`, `/`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, and all digits `0` .. `9`.

You want `[~!@#$%^&*_+\-=]` (escape the `-`).

Comment: You beat me for seconds :)

Comment: Do you have any reference that explains that RegExp uses the range based in the ASCII table order?

Comment: Thank you very much, you resolve my problem quickly. It trouble me long time.

Comment: @Dez http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-characterrange-abstract-operation says that ranges `a-b` are based on the "character value" of the characters `a`, `b`. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type says that strings basically use UCS-2, i.e. the character values in the range 0 .. 127 match ASCII (and 0 .. 255 matches ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1)).

Comment: this is a good one. I almost recommended using [^\d\w]$ instead. Good to know that +-= is actually a range. +1